# How To Display Categories on front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I was wondering if there was a way to loop through WordPress categories like there is for posts. I am trying to display these categories on the front-page.php file of my custom theme. Is there any way to do this? I have tried using functions like wp_list_categories() and different variations of it. However, it only returns the “Uncategorised” category and non of the others.

I was also wondering if there was a way (in this supposed loop or function to display all the different categories) to get the $term_id of the category I have uploaded custom images for each category and would like to grab those as well. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes, both are possible, however, you'll have to post some code to show us what you have currently.

Comment: Thank you so mcuh! Currently I’m trying to work with this code:

foreach(get_categories() as $category) {
          echo '<div><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div>'

However, it still only returns the “undefined” category. When I use it in the front-page.php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem with displaying categories via wp_list_categories() is that by default this function does not display categories with no posts.

Try use this function with parameter "hide_empty=0"

```
<?php wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0');
```

Also u can use get_categories() function

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
) );
 
foreach( $categories as $category ) {

print_r($category);

$category_link = get_category_link( $category->term_id ); 
?>

<a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That worked! It displayed all of the different names of the categories on the page. Is there a way to extract specific pieces of information from each category? For example the category name, id, url, etc.

Comment: I updated code with second example